# sscanf 'conversion lacks type at end of format'

Tags: c, scanf

I'm getting this warning from `sccanf()`:

```
../../../../ext/oedipus/oedipus.c:211: warning: conversion lacks type at end of format
```

Which comes from this line:

```
sscanf(v, "%h", &s);
```

Here `s` is a `short`.

I know I can ignore the warning, but up to this point I was warning free, so I'd like to silence it if possible.  What is `sscanf()` expecting differently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `%hd` for a `short`.  `%h` isn't valid by itself.  From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf):

> **h**
>
> Indicates that the conversion will be one of **d**, **i**, **o**, **u**, **x**, **X**, or **n** and the next pointer is a pointer to a *short int* or *unsigned short int* (rather than *int*).

Please don't ignore warnings - they usually mean something has gone wrong.  This case is a good example - your compiler appeared to do the "right thing", but relying on undefined behaviour is always a bad idea.